# Can I split a feature branch and then merge it back to the origin master branch without any issues?

Tags: git, branching

I'm working on a project where the master branch is protected.

Usual workflow: Always create feature branches off `master` and then send PRs. Once that has been merged into `origin/master`, I can pull it into my local master then create some more feature branches off `local/master` to work.

However I had a branch which was a quite important refactoring (`update-deps-refactor`) and unless this is merged back to the origin master branch, I'm blocked doing other tasks (since I can't pull from `origin/master` until it has been merged)

Can I just branch off `update-deps-refactor` locally and continue to work? So when I send a PR for `feature2` branch, the reviewer can merge at their own pace. Since `update-deps-refactor` and `feature2` will share some common commits, the git diff won't duplicate those commits again and the code reviewer also doesn't have to rereview the common commits between `update-deps-refactor` and `feature2`

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly branch off of any branch. If your `refactor` branch is long-lived, and you need to add a new feature based off it the work you've already done, create `feature2` off the `refactor` branch.

However, those 2 branches are intertwined now. You'll need to regularly pull from `refactor` into `feature2` (in addition to pulling from `main` into `refactor`). Your PR from `feature2` into `refactor` will only reflect the diffs between those 2 branches, but when you open a PR from `refactor` into `main` you will get see diffs from `feature2` as well - something to keep in mind for whoever is reviewing.

In order for the `feature2` PR to be as clean as possible, the changes you make in `feature2` should be completely unrelated to the changes you're making in `refactor`. When you start changing the same functions in the same files on the two branches, that means conflicts. Given your use-case though (the feature depends on the work you're doing in the refactoring) this may be unavoidable.

Given all that, I'd caution about having such a long-lived branch (`refactor`) that you are doing other development on (`feature2`) at the same time. If this is truly a refactoring, adding in new features can complicate the determination that the refactoring was successful (is a bug due to the refactor or the new feature). So while it is possible to branch off of your refactoring branch, I'd evaluate whether you really want to do that, or focus on wrapping up the refactoring first.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a long lived branch. Also they don’t affect the same files either. I just wanted a way to continue working on a separate branch without having to wait for refactor to get merged. 

But I see your point. If the reviewer asks me to make changes in my refactor branch and then submit again,  then my feature branch will have to rebase off refactor before I can continue working on the feature.

Comment: `I just wanted a way to continue working on a separate branch without having to wait for refactoring to get merged` well, everything you do is according to a planning. Both, the refactor and the following tasks are scheduled. they will be released at some point. Ask tech lead or PM when do they want the refactor to be released. That will tell you if you can branch off `refactor` or any other branch. `Also they don’t affect the same files either` if both are changes absolutely unrelated, better branch off `master` and give it a proper name

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase` to move the branches (refactor and feature) when work happens on the other branches (main and refactor) and finally when refactoring is merged.  You can also move the commits from refactor that you need in feature to the base and first merge those into main rebasing refactor and feature on the merge of those changes.

Given new changes in refactor do:

```
git switch feature;
git rebase refactor...feature --onto refactor
```

Graphically you are doing.  From:

```
*    Refactor: new changes feature should be rebased on these
| *  Feature
| *  a commit in Feature
|/
*    Fearure...Refactor (common base of Feature and Refactor)
*    a commit in Refactor
*    Main: before starting refactorring
```

To:

```
*    Feature
*    a commit in feature
*    Refactor: new changes feature should be rebased on these
*    this was the common base now it's just a commit
*    a commit in Refactor
*    Main: before starting refactoring
```

For changes in Main you rebase in two steps first Refactor onto Main then Feature onto the moved Refactor.  Make sure to remember the hash of the base of feature (on create a tempoeary branch for it):

```
git branch tmp/feature-base feature...refactor;
git switch refactor;
git rebase refactor...main --onto main;
git switch feature;
git rebase tmp/feature-base --onto refactor;
git branch -D tmp/feature-base;
```

Graphically from:

```
*   Main: new changes both branches should have these
| * Feature
| * a commit in Feature
| * tmp/feature-base, Refactor
| * a commit in Refactor
|/
*   Refactor...Main: before starting refactoring
```

Intermediate:

```
*   Refactor
*   a commit in refactor
*   Main: new changes both branches should have these
| * Feature
| * a commit in Feature
| * tmp/feature-base: this commit is no longer is the refactor branch but it is in the history of Feature
| * a commit in Refactor
|/
*   before starting refactoring
```

To:

```
*   Feature
*   a commit in Feature
*   Refactor
*   a commit in refactor
*   Main: new changes both branches should have these
*   before starting refactoring
```

Once Refactor is merged into main rebase Feature onto the merge commit, this leads to a semi linear history with features visible and small commits that tell a story about why the code is as.

```
*   Feature
*   a commit on feature
*   merge refactor into main
|\
| * Refactor
| * a commit in refactor
|/
*   before starting refactoring
```

*Don't be affraid of rebasing or merge conflicts.*